# Bindings are correct, but not working (anymore)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, microsoft-metro

These Bindings don't seem to want to work anymore. They were working fine yesterday.

XAML:

```
            <ListBox Name="NotesList" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="NoteTitle" Text="{Binding ElementName=NotesList, Path=SelectedItem.Title, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" FontSize="24" Background="GhostWhite" />
            <TextBox x:Name="NoteContents" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding ElementName=NotesList, Path=SelectedItem.Content, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 50, 0, 0" />
```

Code-behind (C#):

```
public class NoteView
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

and as you can see from the code depicted in the image below, that it is correct and should work. You can also see below, that the contents of the files are being read/set, but it's just not updating the UI.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I've been at it for a while tonight, and am getting nowhere - I have no idea what's up with this code.

[image]

Comment: Other things to note: I have set Capabilities for Documents library, and also added correct File Type Associations - obviously - otherwise it wouldn't have been working yesterday. I have also checked (although there was no need) to make sure that the actual files were not empty - which they weren't.

Comment: As your method GetFilesAsync is probably async, the list 'notes' should be empty. it is not an observable collection, so the control is not notified by new items.

Comment: Please check the Output window of VS12 during runtime! Are there any binding errors?

Comment: Actually, that does change. I just managed to solve my problem too. Will update with answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Binding problem was due to confusion between this, and another, similar project I'm working on.

As you can see from the sample in my question, I set:

`Note = Content`

But, in my XAML, I set:

`Path=SelectedItem.Content` - which is wrong. I should be setting it like this:

`Path=SelectedItem.Note` - since that's what I'm trying to bind to.

So changing from Content to Note in XAML fixed it.